# What is the solution to the differential equation $\frac {dy}{dx} + xy = x$, when $y(0)=-6$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I know about implicit differentiation and integrals, but how do I solve this type of equations?

Comment: If you have learnt about it, you can use an *integrating factor*. (This can be used to solve ODE's of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}+ p(x)y=q(x)$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are functions of $x$.)

Comment: $y=1-7e^{-x^2/2}$

Comment: Can you please explain step by step how to get to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the equation with $e^{x^2/2}$:
$$e^{x^2/2} y' + x e^{x^2/2} y = x e^{x^2/2}.$$

Now the left hand side can be written as a derivative:
$$e^{x^2/2} y' + x e^{x^2/2} y = (e^{x^2/2} y)'.$$

Thus we have,
$$(e^{x^2/2} y)' = x e^{x^2/2}.$$

We can now take the antiderivative of this:
$$e^{x^2/2} y = e^{x^2/2} + C,$$
where $C$ is some constant.

Then we multiply the equation with $e^{-x^2/2}$:
$$y = 1 + C e^{-x^2/2}.$$

Finally we use the condition $y(0) = -6$:
$$-6 = y(0) = 1 + C,$$
i.e.
$$C = -7.$$

Thus we arrive at the solution,
$$y(x) = 1 - 7 e^{-x^2/2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

As said by Minus One-Twelfth any differential equation of the form
$$y'+p(x)y=q(x)$$
can be solved by multiplying through by an 'integrating factor' given by
$$IF=\exp{\left(\int p(x) dx\right)}$$
which gives the new equation
$$\exp{\left(\int p(x) dx\right)}y'+p(x)\exp{\left(\int p(x) dx\right)}y=q(x)\exp{\left(\int p(x) dx\right)}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\exp{\left(\int p(x) dx\right)}y\right)=q(x)\exp{\left(\int p(x) dx\right)}$$
$$\therefore y=\exp{\left(-\int p(x) dx\right)}\int q(x)\exp{\left(\int p(x) dx\right)}dx$$